# Overriding Page Templates, child components get lost from the active route

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm overriding the ProductListPageTemplate like this:

```
 <ng-template cxOutletRef="ProductListPageTemplate">
    <app-product-list-template></app-product-list-template>
 </ng-template>
```

Doing this, the component `cx-product-facet-navigation` has an incorrect behavior with the relative links for queries within a category.

Specifically:

The facets compute the link as

```
<a class="value ng-star-inserted" href="/en/USD/?query=:relevance:allCategories:TCE:productCarBrands:8796093070078" tabindex="-1" data-cx-focus="CHEVROLET">
  <span>
    <span class="label">CHEVROLET</span>
    <span class="count">2</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Instead of

```
<a class="value ng-star-inserted" href="/en/USD/industry-solutions/c/TCE?query=:relevance:allCategories:TCE:productCarBrands:8796093070078" tabindex="-1" data-cx-focus="CHEVROLET">
  <span>
    <span class="label">CHEVROLET</span>
    <span class="count">2</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

So something happens when overriding a template outlet in this way that makes the active route get lost.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, I know why this is happening but haven't yet found time to come with a better suggested solution for you so far. Do you need to use outlets in this case, or could you use an alternative approach as well? If you can further elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, we might be able to unblock you with a different approach.

Comment: Hi Tobias. Sorry for the late response. We just need to have the correct links in the facets, just the normal behaviour after overriding the template as we did.

We did this override, because in this template, we divided the slots into two columns with a 'stack' behaviour, instead of a grid (table). We did this because, otherwise we had plenty of empty spaces due the different sizes of those slots/components cause the sizes are dynamics.

The option Spartacus provide to override the template suits us very well, so we will love to keep that, but be able to use the facets normally.